# set charset in iframe? Not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, utf-8, character-encoding

i have charset set to

`utf8`

in my iframe, when i post data in chrome or firefox it works well, but IE it seems that charset is not utf8. any ideas?

Comment: I just checked source and both tells that charset is utf8, but IE still posts data not in utf8 if launched in IE. Can it be something to do with FLASH? Using form made in flash.